# Avoid require same things several times in several files

Tags: node.js, jestjs, require

I'm using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) as test runner for Google Puppeteer.

In Jest, a `file.test.js` is a suite of tests.

For running tests, I need to require some libraries.

A lot of tests require the same libraries.

Can I avoid requiring these libraries in every test file? I would like to import once somewhere and use everywhere.

e.g.

- `test1.test.js` contains `const path = require('path')`
- `test2.test.js` contains `const path = require('path')`

I would like to write `const path = require('path')` once somewhere and use in `test1.test.js` and `test2.test.js`. I would like to do this both for `node_modules/` and for custom modules.

Comment: You can create a setup file somewhere and set `global.path = require("path")`, instead. Then it's accessible in all tests. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array

Comment: I think an important precision is : why do you want to avoid doing this? nodejs caches anything you require, meaning there is absolutely no performance hit in requiring something from multiple locations in your project.

Comment: @ÉvelyneLachance only for code reuse.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this works as i need. thanks.